# Layout file, how can i list the contents in layout

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like the view the country list, state list and city list in the layout side menu in all the pages.

```
<div class="container side-menu">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <?php $countries = array();?>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <?php foreach($countries as $country) { ?>
                        <?php echo "<option>".$country['name']."</option>"; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <?php $categories = array(); ?>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
                        <?php echo "<option>".$category['name']."</option>"; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your current code? What exactly is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables to layout.phtml globally in ZF2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439364/how-to-pass-variables-to-layout-phtml-globally-in-zf2)