# How to access services from a view script in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: migration, service-locator, zend-view, zend-framework3, zend-servicemanager

I have a custom authentication service and in ZF2 I accessed this as follows:

**`Application/view/layout/layout.phtml`**

```
$authenticationService = $this->getHelperPluginManager()
    ->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('AuthenticationService');
$currentIdentity = $authenticationService->getIdentity();
```

Now the `Zend\ServiceManager#getServiceLocator()` is deprecated.

**How to get a service available in a view script (or concrete in this case in the layout) in ZF3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to assign a global view variable in the `onBootstrap(...)`:

```
namespace Application;
use ...
class Module
{

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        ...
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->authenticationService = $serviceManager->get('AuthenticationService');
    }
    ...
}
```

Another (perhaps an even better/cleaner) solution is to use a `ViewHelper`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18549487/2019043).

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose there is already [Identity View Helper](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-view/helpers/identity/)

As documentation says

```
// Use it any .phtml file
// return user array you set in AuthenticationService or null
$user = $this->identity();
```

Comment: I am completely agreed with you!