# PHP Array help needed ( beginner )

Tags: php

I need help with my array, it is 2 hours that I am there and I still do not understand. Let me explain, when I ask to display the second line of my table, this one shows me the second column of all my lines.

recover the query ( label.php ) :

```
class Services_Label extends Services_Abstract
{
    public function getlibelle()
    {
        $sRequest = 'SELECT NAME FROM menu WHERE id_application = 2';
        $this->executeQueries($sRequest);
        $aResult = $this->getAllRows();
        $this->freeStatement();

        return $aResult;
    }
```

create the value (GestidentController.php) :

```
$oMessage = new Services_Label();
$toto = $oMessage->getlibelle();

foreach ($toto as $data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value[2];      
    }
}
```

the output with `echo $value[2]` -> `isippimnnruud`

the answer with `$value`

> Prise en chargeListe des d�p�tsSaisie par flashageSupervisionSupervision des fluxSuivi des flux informatiquesAdministrationContr�le des RADMContr�le des RPECSurveillanceJournalJournal de bordAudit des depots

I expected the output of `$value[2]` to be `Saisie par flashage`

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: unfortunately you're array output ($value) doesn't really appear to be an array.. could you show us `echo '<pre>'. print_r($value, 1) .'</pre>';`

Comment: it gives me the same thing but with a return to the line

Comment: Can you show with toto instead of value ? I think that would be more interesting to see what's coming out from the db

Comment: That appears to be a string value? (Otherwise it should say `Array` somewhere, and contain () and [] as well.) Then I don’t see how `echo $value[2]` could ever result in `isippimnnruud` - which is not contained in the output you have shown _at all_.

Comment: Side note: You have an encoding issue, given the `�`'s.

Comment: This is also [a repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371226/i-dont-understand-why-my-variable-is-null).

Comment: Then, let's cote to close one of them as dupe, and explain to @Nico why he should not do that