# Access Controller's action variable in layout in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to access the variable in layout in zend framework, how can I do that. I searched a lot but can't find any thing useful or helpful for me. Below are the links that I already tried so admin please don't mark this question as duplicate one..

Thanks..

[Zend Framework 2 - Layout and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360040/zend-framework-2-layout-and-variable)

[access controller action variables to zf2 layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665010/access-contoller-action-variables-to-zf2-layout)

**Senario**

I have a link in `layout.phtml` that I want to display on conditional bases. Like some user of my sites cannot see that link but other can do. That condition comes from the databases that I have but I don't know how to access that in `layout.phtml`

**Example**

```
<?php if($this->check == true) {?><a href="#">This Link</a><?php } ?>
```

if `$this->check == true` than show the link otherwise not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem

write the below code in `IndexController's` **init Function**

```
$this->_helper->layout()->myvar = $someValue;
```

and access it in the layout by this code

```
$this->placeholder('Zend_Layout')->myvar;
```

One has to so this for each controller that he/she has in his/her application. Otherwise will get an error regarding undefined variable.

**Reference:**

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html

Line 15 of first code listing....

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable from the action to the view like

```
$this->view->check = true;
```

Then access it in the view like `$this->check` and do the checking

```
if($this->check){
  //Do something
}
else{
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: I have more 20 action/views, how can pass the variable in all those actions/views. Plus the link is in the layout not in the view how can I make that link invisible from any other view.....

Comment: You have to pass from each action and do the hiding in the corresponding layout of the view.